# js hide function

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the page is loaded (the first dropdown (div StatusID) is dynamically populated from the mysql db) or the user selects Unemployed - EI from the first dropdown box, the div status_sub_6 shows the second select statement.

My .hide .show function activates fine on change but the function hides the second dropdown list on the loading of the page even if the dynamically populated values of the first select (StatusID) meet the compare criteria.

I'm sure that I need an onload function which overrides the following .js code but would really appreciate a bit of help in composing the additional code.

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#status_sub_6').hide();

     $('#StatusID').change(function () {
        if ($('#StatusID option:selected').text() == "Unemployed - EI"){
            $('#status_sub_6').show();
        }
         else { 
              $('#status_sub_6').hide();
         }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by *triggering* a change event right after load.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    ...
    // your current code
    ...
    $('#StatusID').trigger('change'); // trigger a change
});
```

Comment: only trigger on load when criteria met

Comment: @Huangism - The criteria is being checked inside the change handler.

Comment: I chose this one as it seemed the most logical to me and funtioned exactly as I needed.  You guys are great.  I hope to be able to contribute to someone else's problem in the future as many have helped me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$(function() {
   $('#status_sub_6').hide();
   $(document).on('change', '#StatusID', function () {
      if ($('#StatusID option:selected').text() == "Unemployed - EI"){
        $('#status_sub_6').show();
      }
      else { 
        $('#status_sub_6').hide();
      }
   });

   $('#StatusID').change();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if ($('#StatusID option:selected').text() == "Unemployed - EI"){
        $('#status_sub_6').hide();
    }

     $('#StatusID').change(function () {
        if ($('#StatusID option:selected').text() == "Unemployed - EI"){
            $('#status_sub_6').show();
        }
         else { 
              $('#status_sub_6').hide();
         }
    });
});
```

or a bit more elegant solutions:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    toggleSub();

    $('#StatusID').change(function () {
        toggleSub();
    });
});

function toggleSub() {
    if ($('#StatusID option:selected').text() == "Unemployed - EI") {
        $('#status_sub_6').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('#status_sub_6').show();
    }
}
```